# jQuery AJAX request internet explorer php file -> NO / html file -> YES

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, internet-explorer

I have the following jQuery code and a mindbreaking problem in internet explorer, where else...

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    //url: "test.html",
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    error:function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown+" -- "+status+" -- "+xhr.statusText);
    },
    success:function(callback) {
        alert("Success, also in IE");
    },
    async: false
}).responseText;
```

My problem is that IE does not "accept" the test.php file with the same test content like the test.html file!!! With the html file the script works, but I want to run a php script using the ajax request... Whats the problem?

THANK YOU!

Comment: **DO NOT use synchronous AJAX.** You can access the `responseText` inside the `success` callback, too!

Comment: What's happening in IE that isn't what you expect/want to happen? Do you get Javascript errors? Does the `error` callback get executed rather than the `success` one?

Comment: thank you for the fast answer. the error and success inside the ajax request are just to see whats happening in IE. for example the whole content of my test.html is "test", IE returns correctly "test", but i have to send a request to a php file... and this does not work. in IE i get only the error! what do i wrong?

Comment: When you say "i get only the error", what is it you mean? Is it the `alert()` in your error callback, or is it an actual Javascript error thrown by the browser?

Comment: in IE I get only the error alert() when calling the test.php file! with the test.html it works...

Comment: i want to check the recaptcha using jquery ajax, so i need to call a php file... but it does not work with IE

Comment: what does the `alert(...)` say? What's the actual error shown?

Comment: What version of IE? Does your server have a MIME type associated with PHP? Can you parse the file if you go to it alone? (http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/php-mimetype.htm)

Comment: the actual error shown in IE using the code above shows "[object Error] -- error -- error"

Comment: try removing `async: false, cache: false, dataType: "text"`. They are not necessary anyways, and you could isolate the problem better...

Comment: does not work... when i remove async, it do not work in ff anymore

Comment: i have found out, that it must have to do with the server settings... because the same code works on antoher server as well with IE as with FF... but what settings?

Answer (score 1):

**The solution for the problem above is:**

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');  
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, pre-check=0, no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, post-check=0');
```

For the Internet Explorer the headers were missing or not set correctly by the server...